# How to determine cut-off value for binomial glmm?

Tags: r, glmm, caret, rocr

I have a dataset composed of an urbanization index (continuous variable) for multiple host species (random effect). I want to determine if there is a relationship between urbanization and disease prevalence. I have been asked to provide sensitivity analysis evaluating different cut-off values. We currently use a 60% cut-off value for the response variable to distinguish a healthy test result from a diseased test result. However, I need to determine how the sensitivity will change if we say use a 45% cutoff value or a 70% cut-off value instead of 60%. Below is some made-up data that is set up in a similar way to my own.

```
    df <- data.frame (serology  = rep(c(22,76,30,56,80,49,50,31,45,66,67,65,73,88),5),
          urbanization = rep(c(10,75,20,22,39,30,40,77,53,50,60,70,90,91),5),
          species = rep(c("dog","cat","horse","pig","rabbit","ferret","crow"),10))
        
    df = cbind(df,health=ifelse((df$serology)>60, 1,0))

index = sample(1:nrow(df), size = .80 * nrow(df))
train = df[index, ]
test = df[-index, ]

model = glmmTMB(health~urbanization + (1|species),data=test, family="binomial")
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is there a reason to have a cutoff at all? I know plenty of machine learning classification tutorials will teach this so you can evaluate metrics like accuracy and $F_1$ score, but there are compelling reasons to evaluate the raw probability predictions, too.

Comment: The reason in this instance is that a reviewer requested it. I agree but we are trying to appease the reviewers request.